# How do I parse this kind of json string in PHP, since json_decode not working?

Tags: php, json

I read a data from URL & I get the response in below json format:

```
'"{\r\n \"data\": \"\",\r\n \"error\": \".\",\r\n \"success\": \"\"\r\n}"'
```

Since after using json_decode($aboveStr, true); it outputs the following string format:

```
{"data": "","error": "","success": ""}
```

I want the output in array.

Comment: That string is encoded twice, you need to decode it twice.

Comment: that worked! thanks :)

Comment: the proper thing to do, however, is to fix whatever program is encoding the JSON twice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for some reason, your input string has been encoded into JSON twice, so you need to call `json_decode()` twice:

```
$array = json_decode(json_decode($aboveStr), true);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to decode your string twice by using `json_decode` twice. Try:

```
print_r(json_decode(json_decode($aboveStr), TRUE));
```

It prints

```
Array ( [data] => [error] => . [success] => )
```